# The query did not execute properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
$data = User::where('inet_id', "like", "%" . $inet . "%")
         ->orWhere('email', "like", "%" . $email . "%")
         ->orWhere('phone', "like", "%" . $phone . "%")
         ->get();
```

1. It only executes the query when searching all 3 data once. But I want to search by separate data too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `when`

```php
$data = User::where(function($q)use($inet,$email,$phone){
      $q->when(!empty($inet), function ($query) use($inet) {
            $query->where('inet_id', 'like', "%{$inet}%");
         })->when(!empty($email), function ($query) use ($email) {
            $query->orWhere('email', 'like', "%{$email}%");
         })->when(!empty($phone), function ($query) use ($phone) {
            $query->orWhere('phone', 'like', "%{$phone}%");
      })
    })->get();
```

Comment: No problem :) One sidenote, to "future-proof" this code, I'd put the entire `::when()` in a `where(function($subQuery) { ... });` block, so that if you need to add another non-like check it doesn't conflict. I.e. `WHERE (... OR ... OR ...) AND/OR ...` vs `WHERE ... OR ... OR ... AND/OR ...`

Comment: i thought at first instance same think but i thought op is looking for executing where only it has value so avoided .l

Comment: All good :) Just something I would have added, but no worries; this answers the immediate question. Cheers!

Comment: it doesn't filter the data if i enter the data as 0.

Comment: @QuốcAnhNguyễn.check my updated answer.if its still issue let me know

Comment: @JohnLobo When I enter search data=0 it won't filter properly. It has taken all the data in the database

Comment: data=0 means .can you show how it is .can you show full method code